# No output of array of strings

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to create an array of strings
Below is the program

```
char *s[6];
int n=6,i=0;
char str[10];
while(n--)
{
    scanf("%s",str);
        s[i]=str;
        i++;
}
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    printf("%s\n",s[i]);
```

Six strings are accepted from the keyboard, but nothing is displayed on the output.
Can anyone help me out here?
Thanks!

Comment: `n` is 0 at start of for loop. also all of your strings will point at the last one scanned..

Comment: `char *s[5];` can hold five strings(`char *`).

Answer (score 4):

```
s[i]=str;
```

You are assigning same `str` to all `s`. All strings would be same on printing. If last string is empty for some reason, all would be empty.

Moreover you should reset `n` to `5` before second loop.

## Fixes

```
while(n--)
{
    scanf("%s",str);
    if(i >= 6) break;  /* 1. Can not go beyond 6 */
    s[i]=malloc(strlen(str) + 1);  /* 2. Allocate */
    if(s[i]) strcpy(s[i], str); /* 3. Copy */
    i++;

}
n = 5; /* 4. reset */
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%s\n",s[i]);
...

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) free(s[i]); /* 5. free */
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible without dynamic allocation?

Comment: @Ravi yes use `char s[6][MAX_STRING_LENGTH]`, but you still need `strcpy` or read directly in `s[i]`

Comment: @MohitJain don't you know about strdup()?

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt Yes `strdup` would work for unix type systems (Make sure to free at end). But you must note at the same time that it not part of the ISO C standard itself and is a POSIX extension.

Comment: @MohitJain of course it must be freed at the end, just like malloc().  I wasn't asking if it would work, I was pointing out that it's better.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt Again as I said it is not standard and thus has portability issues unless your targets are limited to posix compliant systems.

Answer (score 3):

The address of `str` is fixed. Thus in statement

```
s[i]=str;
```

each element of the array of character pointers s gets the same address.
You coudl change the code snippet at least the following way

```
#include <string.h>
//...
#define N 6

//...

char s[N][10];
int n = N, i = 0;
char str[10];

while ( n-- )
{
    scanf("%9s", str );
    strcpy( s[i], str );
    i++;
}
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    puts( s[i] );
```

The while loop would be better to write as a for loop

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    scanf("%9s", str );
    strcpy( s[i], str );
}
```

Also pay attention to that if your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays and the array s is a local variable of a function (for example of main) you could define it the following way

```
int n;

printf( "Enter the number of strings you are going to enter: " );
scanf( "%d", &n );

if ( n <= 0 ) n = N;
char s[n][10];
```